# How to reapply changeset that was rolled back before

Tags: svn, merge

How can I reapply a changeset that was rolled back to a previous version? Naturally I would use another merge with the desired revision, but the command seems to be a no-op - nothing is merged, and `svn status` reveals no changes after the merge. The only way I found to do this was use the `--ignore-ancestry` option, but it just does not seem right.

What I try to do is the following:

- The repository is at revision `1000`
- We begin with the `trunk` rollback to revision `500` by creating a branch `branches/rollback` and then executing `svn merge -r HEAD:500 .` in the branch WC
- Afterwards we would like to reapply the changeset of revision `700`, which we try to accomplish by executing `svn merge -c 700 ^/trunk .`, which does not work (actually: does nothing at all)
- If we add the `--ignore-ancestry` option to the previous command, it does what we want, but does not feel right.
- Afterwards, we would reintegrate the branch back to the `trunk` to have it in the needed state: revisions 501-1000 rolled back, revision 700 reapplied.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

> - The repository is at revision 1000
> - We begin with the trunk rollback to revision 500 by creating a branch branches/rollback and then executing svn merge -r HEAD:500 . in the branch WC

Okay, I'm not understanding something here. Why not simply:

```
$ svn cp -r500 $REPO/trunk@500 $REPO/branches/rollback
```

This will create a version of the `rollback` branch that matches revision 500 from trunk.

> - Afterwards we would like to reapply the changeset of revision 700, which we try to accomplish by executing `svn merge -c 700 ^/trunk`, which does not work (actually: does nothing at all)

If you did this on your rollback branch's working copy:

```
$ svn merge -c 700
```

If would include revision 700 in your working copy of the branch. The reason this didn't work is that `svn:mergeinfo` said that Revision 700 was already in the rollback branch, and thus Subversion won't reapply it. `svn:mergeinfo` isn't affected by reverse merges, so the rollback of revisions 501 to 1000 didn't affect `svn:mergeinfo`.

> - If we add the --ignore-ancestry option to the previous command, it does what we want, but does not feel right.

Here's what the Subversion book says about `--ignore-ancestry`:

> The --ignore-ancestry option prevents merge tracking and thus ignores mergeinfo, neither considering it nor recording it.

Therefore, when you used `--ignore-ancestry`, Subversion merges revision 700 whether it was already applied or not.

> - Afterwards, we would reintegrate the branch back to the trunk to have it in the needed state: revisions 501-1000 rolled back, revision 700 reapplied.

I'm not sure the reintegration will do anything at this point. There's nothing to *integrate* since there are no real changes on the rollback branch itself. All the changes on the rollback branch are changes that took place in trunk.

It use to be that reintegration would do a two way merge which would force trunk to match the branch. However, reintegration has been deprecated in Subversion versions 1.6 or 1.7 (I forget which). You attempt to use the `--reintegration` switch, and Subversion will complain. I can't say what Subversion would do in this case.

If you simply want to rollback trunk, rollback trunk:

```
$ svn co $REPO/trunk
$ cd trunk
$ svn merge -r1000:701 .   # Rolls back revisions 701 to 1000
$ svn merge -r699:500  .   # Rolls back revisions 500 to 699
$ svn commit -m" Removed all changes since Rev 500 except 700"
```

you could automate this a bit, and rollback and commit each revision separately. This way, if you decide to reapply a certain change, you can reverse merge that reverse merge revision that did the original reverse merge, and... Okay, an example:

```
for revision in {1000..500}
do
    [[ $revision -eq 700 ]] && continue  # Skip Revision #700
    svn merge -c -$revision
    svn commit -m "Backing out Revision $revision"
done
```

Let's say you decided you now want to include revision 823 back into trunk. You do a `svn log` and see:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1230 | mike | ......

Backing out Revision 823
```

You now know Revision 1230 was backed out revision 823 in your repo. So...

```
$ svn merge -c -1230
```

This will remove the changes that Revision 1230 did -- which was backing out Revision 823. So, after you commit your changes, Revision 823 is now back into the repo.

You might be able to edit `svn:mergeinfo` to fix it with the correct revision ranges. However, manually modifying this property isn't highly encouraged. One mistake, and your merge history will no longer work.

Usually, if we find we've messed up everything so badly, we simply make a branch and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least *some ways* to have needed result with separate branch and 1 way in just-trunk

**Branch's Ways**

1. Nearest to your: properly use cherry-pick merge (define merge-source URL - it can be trunk /or even branch? untested/)
2. More SVN-way: reverse-merge two ranges in single command (skip rev.700)

**Natural way**

Reverse-merge two ranges in single command (skip rev.700) in trunk

Comment: We already use cherry picking with a source URL (fixed in question code). Skipping is not an option since we want to be able to test in between, and there are ~30 revisions that need to be re-applied. Any other ideas?